# Programming ASP.NET MVC3 user authentication with a windows Domain "simulation"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-server-2008

I'm programming an ASP.NET MVC3 project, and I am required to implement user authentication via Windows Domain / Active Directory.

However, during the development period I have no access to the domain, and installing a local Windows Domain is not possible (I'm developing the application on my private modest computer).

Is there a way to have a domain "simulation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your development is on the local machine which is not connected to a Windows Active Domain, you can authenticate against the Local Machine.  This will simulate Active Directory authentication, but nothing more (that I know of).

Comment: And LOCALMACHINE\username will act just as DOMAIN\username ?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague.  I do not know how you are using the fully qualified username (domain\username).  localmachine\user and domain\user are absolutely two different users.  So depending on how you wrote your application it may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider an accordingly set up **virtual machine**.